# Creating a custom password protect file program

Tags: c#, security, filesystems

I know this isn't a strait up code question, but I'm trying make a program that could possible be running in the background of my computer, and allow me to leave my files/folders where they are, and upon double clicking on a file/folder a dialog box comes up asking for a password. All these programs that are on the market require you to move files around, create new volumes; I don't want that, I want simplicity. One dialog box with password promt, then file/folder opens. My question is what do I need to look into coding wise to make this possible? Thanks for any advice/tips. :)

```
  FileSecurity()
```

Also Is this something that can only be done with NTFS and not FAT?

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect when someone click or double click a folder, so no, it is not possible.

Comment: I actually found a project that someone wrote that is pretty much exactly what Im looking for: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20880/Folder-protection-for-Windows-using-Csharp-and-con

Answer (score 0):

you can use FileSystemWatcher to detect when a file is opened and handle the open event, but unfortunately you cannot prevent its execution

Comment: I actually found a project that someone wrote that is pretty much exactly what Im looking for: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20880/Folder-protection-for-Windows-using-Csharp-and-con

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only three ways how to SECURELY protect file:

- write filesystem driver (similar used by antivirus software for example), but isn't not possible in C#
- encrypt all files when user locks folder and decrypt them back when user unlocks folder.
- for non-admin accounts, you can set privileges (and on NTFS also built-in file encryption) in such a way, that without admin password user can't access them

Method used in [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20880/Folder-protection-for-Windows-using-Csharp-and-con) you mentioned is not secure at all (any user can just rename the folder back to get access to protected files). Though you can use the same trick to run you program automatically when user double-clicks protected folder and unlock files if user enter correct password.

Comment: Program in article "locks" folder by renaming it from (lets say) "abc" to "abc.{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}". But user can rename the folder back to "abc" (thus making it unlocked again) without need of any password.